# Java derby database server won't start anymore

Tags: java, database, derby

I inherited some source code that uses a derby database but starting the server doesn't work anymore.

```
public void startDatabase(){
    try {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
        System.setProperty("derby.system.home", "D:\\runtime-my.product\\log");

        NetworkServerControl nsc = new NetworkServerControl(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 1527)
        nsc.start(null);
        nsc.ping();
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When `nsc.ping()` is exectued, the following exception is thrown:

```
Exception: java.lang.Exception: DRDA_NoIO.S:Could not connect to Derby Network Server on host 127.0.0.1, port 1527: Connection refused: connect
```

Is there anything obvious missing or wrong with those lines of codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check whether the server is started. You need to start the server explicitly. or via
setting the system property `derby.drda.startNetworkServer=true`.

Answer (score 2):

It takes a while from the NetworkServerControl constructor returns, before the socket is ready for connections. On my machine about 50 ms. I changed your example like so:

```
NetworkServerControl nsc = new NetworkServerControl(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 1527);
    nsc.start(null);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Attempting to ping...");
            nsc.ping();
            break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        Thread.sleep(10);
    }
```

It succeeded on the 5. attempt...